# On convergence of the same sequence under two different norms.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let, $f\in A=L^1(\mathbb R^n) \cap L^2(\mathbb R^n).$

Does there exists $\{g_n\}_n \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n),$ the space of all Schwartz class functions on $\mathbb R^n,$ with $g_n {\rightarrow}^{L^1} f$   &  $g_n {\rightarrow}^{L^2} f ?$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ The space of all smooth compactly supported functions on $\mathbb R^n,$ $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n),$ is dense in $A$ but in both spaces, can we say whether same sequence exists which converges to $f$ under $2$ different norms ?

Any small hints .
Thanks in adv.

Comment: Did you look at the proof of the density of $C^\infty_c$ in these spaces ? ...

Comment: Yes, a long time ago.

Comment: May be you should read it again now.